# How to put a pie chart according to latitude and longitude values on the map generated with Topojson using d3(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

JavaScript code for generating the pie chart for each latitude and longitude values in the CSV record on the topojson map.
I have to create custom marker for each latitude and longitude values in topojson map so want to create pie chart as a marker.

Comment: Please explain in a concrete example what is your problem.
Could you also show us what you've achieved so far?

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728).